# Remove a marker it add itself Again

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm adding a marker on google maps and i get the marker on hashmap

```
{42=com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker@cc9eb81}
```

This way, Now when I add the marker all fine and I remove the marker once all great but sometimes
The marker add itself after I remove it on the hashmap and on the map itself!!
`/MarkerList: {42=com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker@cc9eb81}` In log CAT

The code is simply as I said simple and clean add remove. that's it And I do remove the marker from hashmap after I remove it on the map but it adds itself after removing directly Any known bugs on markers or something?

Comment: It's hard to help you without the source code.

Comment: Of course sorry for that ill update today <3 I wanna solve this really

Comment: Please can you post your full code so that we can reproduce this issue from our side?